# Can't get bind parameter name in sqlite3

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm trying to get the names of parameters but something is going wrong.

**Code:** (minimal code to re-produce the problem)

```
var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
var rc: Int32 = 0
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &self.db)
if rc != SQLITE_OK
{
    print("cant open")
}
var statement: OpaquePointer? = nil
let sql = "insert into testtable values(?123);"
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil)
if rc != SQLITE_OK
{
    print("cant prepare")
}
print(String(cString: sqlite3_bind_parameter_name(statement, 1))) // returns nil
sqlite3_finalize(statement)
sqlite3_close(db)
```

I get parameter names if I use `@AAA`, `:AAA`, `$AAA` but I get `nil` if I use `?123`( `?NNN` format). But according to [website](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_parameter_name.html) I should get `?123` as `String`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: in the above question which is correct to do? this sqlite3_close(db) or this sqlite3_close(statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `?123`, the `123` is the index. So you need to pass `123`, not `1`, to the call to `sqlite3_bind_parameter_name`.

You can see more in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions.

Comment: I thought `?NNN` format works same like other formats( `?AAA`, `@AAA`, `$AAA`). Thank you for clarification.

Comment: The ones with `AAA` are named. The one with `NNN` is numbered. The named ones start with 1 and go up. The numbered ones have that specific number.

Comment: @rmaddy in the above question which is correct to do? this sqlite3_close(db) or this sqlite3_close(statement)

Comment: @ArgaPK See the documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html